# Why was the police station shown to be empty at night?

Tags: plot-explanation, three-billboards-outside-ebbing

In *Three Billboards Outside Ebbing, Missouri*, Mildred planned to burn down the police station at night. Dixon was present there accidentally, to collect a letter. It seems she knew that the police station would be empty at night.

The police stations are manned 24*7, aren't they? Is there any reason behind leaving the police station unmanned that night?

Comment: "police stations are manned 24*7" Of course not. A simple Google search could have told you that.

Comment: @BCdotWEB - I've never known a police station to not be manned 24/7/365 [other than some teeny one-cop stations in the middle of nowhere], so that's news to me too.

Comment: I also question this but a "teeny one-cop station in the middle of nowhere" does seem to describe Ebbing.

Comment: ["Of the more than 18,000 law enforcement agencies in the United States, about 80% have fewer than 25 sworn officers. That doesn’t leave enough staff to keep a lobby or desk open 24/7."](https://www.quora.com/Are-all-U-S-police-stations-open-24-7)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In many small towns, it occurs quite often where a Sheriff's Station may not be staffed 24/7.  I even found a station on google where you might even need to call a non 911 phone number in order to talk to a deputy.

Comment: A lot of the substations won’t always have personnel in them too because they’re not meant to hold suspects. Just to help process them locally before transport to the county jail and for resupply for officers. So many times they’ll sit empty.